# How to suppress the interpretation of double brackets in org mode?

Tags: org-mode

How to suppress the interpretation of double brackets in org mode?

Some of my text heavily used the double brackets but org-mode defined it to be links. Can I suppress the interpretation of double brackets, or more conveniently, temporarily suppress it where I do not need it to be interpreted as links.

I've tried quote (~~ ==) it as code but it does not work.

The only way I found is to embedded them into an EXAMPLE or SRC.

Are there any other methods, maybe some OPTIONS?

Thanks very much!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `M-x org-toggle-link-display` to only disable the collapsing of the double brackets, although this still formats the text within the brackets as a link (blue, underlined).

The formatting of bracketed links can be disabled entirely by changing `org-highlight-links`, which is set to `'(bracket angle plain radio tag date footnote)` by default. By removing `bracket` from this list, bracketed items will not be treated as links anymore. This can be done by `setf`ing the variable, or via `M-x customize`.

When you change this list, you have to use `M-x org-mode-restart` for the changes to take effect (see `C-h v org-highlight-links` for more details).

Comment: Hi, why my Emacs do not have `org-highlight-links`? Btw, are there any OPTIONS to do this? just like `prettyentities` that both have `org-toggle-pretty-entities` command and `entitiespretty` OPTION

Comment: I don't think there is an org-mode option for startup or export that does this. Maybe setting a file variable works, like described in https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html? The `org-highlight-links` is aliased to `org-activate-links`, so you might try that as well. Did you load org-mode before trying to find the variable?

Answer (score 1):

You can also customize the variable `org-activate-links` with a local value by putting this line at the beginning of the file:

```
;; -*- mode: org; org-activate-links: '(angle plain radio tag date footnote); -*-
```